Microsoft Teams integration in Java Play or Springboot framework for sending messages
I am working on creating a Java API for Microsoft integration with webhook URL for sending teams messages with API. Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem.
This is my Json data
{
    "webhookUrl": "<--data-->",
    "message": "<--data-->"
}

This is my code
package controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import models.TeamsNotification;
import play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.Result;
import services.TeamsNotificationService;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class TeamsNotificationController extends Controller {

    private final TeamsNotificationService notificationService;
    private final HttpExecutionContext ec;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Inject
    public TeamsNotificationController(TeamsNotificationService notificationService, HttpExecutionContext ec, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.ec = ec;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> sendNotification(Http.Request request) {
        JsonNode json = request.body().asJson();
        if (json == null) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(badRequest("Expecting JSON data"));
        }

        TeamsNotification notification;
        try {
            notification = objectMapper.treeToValue(json, TeamsNotification.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(badRequest("Invalid JSON data"));
        }

        return notificationService.sendNotification(notification).thenApplyAsync(response -> {
            if (response.get("status").asText().equals("success")) {
                return ok(response);
            } else {
                return internalServerError(response);
            }
        }, ec.current());
    }
}

This is the error I am getting
INFO  p.a.h.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions - Registering exception handler: guice-provision-exception-handler
2024-05-21 17:04:00 INFO  play.api.http.EnabledFilters  Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

    play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
    play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
2024-05-21 17:04:00 INFO  play.api.Play  Application started (Dev) (no global state)
2024-05-21 17:04:00 WARN  play.filters.CSRF  [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in headers for /sendNotification

I was trying to send teams channel notifications with the Java Play API  framework. However, I am getting some errors in my  regarding CSRF token authentication error. Can anyone share any code stuff they have done for MS teams integration, even if it's a GitHub link, it will be very helpful.

Remove the CSRF Filter if you're not gonna use CSRF tokens?

It worked! I thought the Webhook URL needed an Authentication token. Thanks for the clarification.
